# Only allow listener event to run if class exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

I have built a Progress bar Javascript object that updates a progress bar when a user clicks on left or right buttons which have "click" event listeners binded to them.
I only want these buttons to trigger the click event if they have a certain class attached to them, in this case a class called "progress-bar-ok".
I can't seem to think of a way to do this in my code so far. Here is my code:

Javascript Object:

```
//Progress Bar
var ProgressBar = function(element, startVal, endVal, step, addLefts, addRights) {
    this.element = element;
    this.endVal = endVal;
    this.currentVal = startVal;
    this.step = step;
    this.addLefts = addLefts;
    this.addRights = addRights;
    var self = this;    
}

ProgressBar.prototype.initializeProgressBar = function() {
    jQuery(this.element).progressbar({
        value : this.currentVal,
        max   : this.endVal,
        step  : this.step
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < this.addLefts.length; i++) {
        this.addLefts[i].addEventListener("click", this.removeAmount.bind(this), false);
    }   
    for(var i = 0; i < this.addRights.length; i++) {
        this.addRights[i].addEventListener("click", this.addAmount.bind(this), false);
    }   
}

ProgressBar.prototype.addAmount = function() {  
    if(this.currentVal < this.endVal) {
        this.currentVal += this.step;       
        this.update();
    }       
}

ProgressBar.prototype.removeAmount = function() {
    console.log(self);
    if(this.currentVal > 0) {
        this.currentVal -= this.step;
        this.update();
    }

}

ProgressBar.prototype.update = function() {
    jQuery(this.element).progressbar({
        value : this.currentVal
    });
}
```

Javascript Client Code

```
//Progress Bar
        var addLefts = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-lft");
        var addRights = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-right");
        var progressBar = new ProgressBar("#progress-bar", 0, jQuery(".signup-part").length, 1, addLefts, addRights);
        progressBar.initializeProgressBar();
```

So as you can see, the 'addLefts' and 'addRights' that have click listeners attached to them I only want to fire the 'addAmount' and 'removeAmount' functions if the class "progress-bar-ok" exists.
Is there a way to incorporate this into my code?
Thanks

Comment: "that" class? what class? what event?

Comment: @KevinB read the top of the post, class is 'progress-bar-ok' and the events are registered in the initializeProgressBar function.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an element with a class exists in the DOM like this

```
if ($('.progress-bar-ok').length) {
    your code
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I know this I just want to keep the functionality within my object.

Comment: Ok, then you can check if your object has the class
if ($(this).hasClass('progress-bar-ok')) {
    your code
}

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery to create your event handlers you can take advantage of [Delegated Events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), which will only be triggered when the targets have the class you specify. In this case you could use  `".progress-bar-ok"` as your selector and only items with that class will trigger the event.

Here's parts of your code updated:

```
ProgressBar.prototype.initializeProgressBar = function() {
    jQuery(this.element).progressbar({
        value : this.currentVal,
        max   : this.endVal,
        step  : this.step
    });

    var removeAmount = this.removeAmount.bind(this);
    $(addLeft).on("click", ".progress-bar-ok", function() {
        removeAmount();
    });

    var addAmount = this.addAmount.bind(this);
    $(addRights).on("click", ".progress-bar-ok", function() {
        addAmount();
    });
}

var progressBar = new ProgressBar("#progress-bar", 0, jQuery(".signup-part").length, 1, ".btn-lft", ".btn-right");
```

I've changed your constructor to take in your jQuery selectors for classes you want to target, and you can see how I am attaching the event handler using jQuery.

I've also put together a simple runnable example demonstrating this effect. I've got two `<ul>` tags below that use your classes `btn-lft` and `btn-right`. I've generated a random number of items inside each `<ul>`. Every `<li>` within may randomly be assigned a `progress-bar-ok` class. When items with that class is clicked, the parent `<ul>` is cleared and is filled randomly again. Nothing happens when items without class `progress-bar-ok` are clicked. Run the snippet below to see.

```js
$(function() {
  //generate arbitrary ul content
  generateSide($(".btn-lft"));
  generateSide($(".btn-right"));
});

$(".btn-lft,.btn-right").on("click", ".progress-bar-ok", function() {
  //this is a delegated event, it handles dynamically created items too!
  var ul = $(this).parent();
  generateSide(ul);
});

function generateSide(ul) {
  //add random content to the ul
  var side = ul.hasClass("btn-lft") ? "Left" : "Right";
  ul.empty(); //clear ul
    
  var numberSelected = 0;
  var newItems = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
  for(var i = 0; i < newItems; i++) {
    var li = $("<li>" + side + " " + (i + 1) + "</li>");
    if (Math.random() > 0.5 || (numberSelected === 0 && i === newItems - 1 ))
      li.addClass("progress-bar-ok");
    ul.append(li);
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  float:left;
  width: 100px;
}
.progress-bar-ok {
  color: #4AF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.progress-bar-ok:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="btn-lft">
  <li class="selected">Left 1</li>
</ul>
<ul class="btn-right">
  <li class="selected">Right 1</li>
</ul>
```